# Excel - How to find the max value of a row that has text, and the text corresponds to a number in a different table?

Tags: excel, max

So if I need to find the lead time for a body that needs both an arm and a leg to be completed, the lead time for that body would be the highest lead time between the two. But the row for each body only contains the "arm" or "leg" part number in text, which Lead time is referenced in a different table.

How do I automatically fill out the "Body Lead Time" column based on the table data for each body part and the body part for each body per row?

Thank you

[image: Example]

Comment: You could use an outer MAX with two inner VLOOKUPs or INDEX/MATCHs or XLOOKUPs, as one option.

Comment: @BigBen Could you give me an example on how to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested Max(IF())

```
=MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$5=B8)+($A$2:$A$5=C8),$B$2:$B$5))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter in  versions of Excel that don't have the new Dynamic Arrays.

[image]

Another option is with the new Filter() function

```
=MAX(FILTER($B$2:$B$5,($A$2:$A$5=B8)+($A$2:$A$5=C8)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=MAX(SUMPRODUCT((A9=$A$2:$A$5)*($B$2:$B$5)),SUMPRODUCT((B9=$A$2:$A$5)*($B$2:$B$5)))
```

[image]